# IPs overlaps on L3 cisco 3550 switch?

Tags: cisco, routing, switch

I want to configure my L3 switch to connect multiple devices:

- squid proxy (192.168.1.4)
- web server (192.168.1.6)
- client (192.168.1.11)

something like that:

[image]

the problem is when I configure one interface it worked will:

```
ip address 192.168.1.7 255.255.255.0
```

but when I try(on another interface):

```
ip address 192.168.1.8 255.255.255.0
```

this message returned:

```
192.168.1.0 overlaped with fastethernet0/1
```

this is confusing, because I have used `/24` as a mask.

and even when I try:

```
ip address 192.168.2.8 255.255.255.0
```

I can't connect the webserver(192.168.1.6) to the squid (192.168.2.4)

So is there something I have missed?

Note: I have configured all the interfaces to be `no switchport`.

Comment: Do you want those 3 to stay on the same network? If yes, then you can configure an SVI. If not, then you can configure 3 SVI and configure the related switch's port to the approriate VLAN. Unless you want to set the switch's ports to routing mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So is there something I have missed?

Yes, you've got the following machines that you want in the same /24 subnet:

- squid proxy (192.168.1.4)
- web server (192.168.1.6)
- client (192.168.1.11)

However, you're trying to put each one of them on their own routed interface; this is a very common mistake.  The simplest solution to your problem is to create what Cisco calls a [Switched Vlan Interface (SVI)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/lan-switching/inter-vlan-routing/41860-howto-L3-intervlanrouting.html) for all of 192.168.1.0/24 on your 3550.

Let's assume you're going to use Vlan 10 for all these systems;  it doesn't really matter what vlan number you use, although people tend to avoid vlan 1 for security reasons.  I will make assumptions about which switchport you connected these systems to, however the port numbers should not matter; just be sure that you configure their actual port number in `vlan 10`. The configuration you want to use is:

```
ip routing
!
! many people set vtp to transparent to avoid future problems...
vtp mode transparent
!
vlan 10
 state active
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 description [Squid Proxy]
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 description [Web Server]
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 description [Client]
 switchport access vlan 10
 switchport mode access
!
interface Vlan10
 ip address 192.168.1.254 255.255.255.0
 no ip proxy-arp
 no ip directed-broadcast
 no shut
!
! Add a default route on a different SVI if you want these systems
! to route through the 3550 to other networks
```

Now configure your squid proxy, web server, and client to use 192.168.1.254 as the default gateway.

Finally, consider using [`switchport nonnegotiate`](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/) on Fa0/1, Fa0/2, and Fa0/3.

Comment: thanks, amazing answer,but what is the reason of the options `no ip proxy-arp`
 ,`no ip directed-broadcast`

Comment: [`ip proxy-arp`](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5279/why-are-routers-not-answering-arp-broadcasts/5280#5280) is enabled by default, but it tends to cause more problems than necessary and is occasionally considered a security risk.  `ip directed-broadcast` is also enabled by default and can also be a security risk.  I usually disable these in my infrastructure unless there is a good reason to keep them on.

Answer (score 2):

Your two IP address statements ARE overlapping. **192.168.1.7** and **192.168.1.8** are in the same /24 subnet: 192.168.1.0/24.

A /24 are 256 addresses ranging from 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.255.

If you want to know more, there are questions about [CIDR subnetting](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/the-slash-after-an-ip-address-cidr-notation) on this SE.

Comment: @Sebestian, what about the 2nd question?

Comment: @Networker not sure, post your config from the 2nd question and try pinging the SQID and Webserver from the L3 switch.

Answer (score 0):

Faster solution :

```
ip routing

vlan 10 
name xxxx

Interface vlan 10
Description xxxx
Ip adress 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 
no shut
Interface vlan 20
Description xxxx
Ip adress 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
no shut
```

On ports:

```
Switchport mode access 
Switchport access vlan 10
no shut
```

and for the squid server:

```
Switchport mode access 
Switchport access vlan 20
no shut
```

Basic config , should get you started.
Now you can use the subnet where you need it , just make the ports access in vlan 10 / vlan 20 for the second subnet
ps: have fun.